# How to set an image as background for a text view based on the size of text

Tags: android

I am doing a chat application program. My problem is that i want to put each text in chat box as like in watsup or any other chat app.I am using custom adapter to design my listview. In the custom adapter class i am using a single text view that have a background a 9patch(60*28) image,but the image seems to be same size for small text and large text.
I want to set the image based on the text size can anybody help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Can't you use `textView.setBackground(R.drawable.bgImage);`?

Comment: but that image will cover entire width i want the image to be in the size of the text entered

Comment: Then you can set ImageView below TextView. When text changed in textview, change size of ImageView ...

Answer (score 0):

set `layout_width` of the `TextView` to `wrap_content`

Comment: @MohammedShehnad I think `TextView` is being stretched because of adapter behaviour. Try to move the `TextView` inside a `layout` so that the adapter will stretch a `layout` not a `TextView`